# Can one see from other program if Gedit is running and contains unsaved text?

Tags: bash, python, gedit

I use Gedit as my favourite text editor. Is it possible to write a script for example in Python or Bash to check if Gedit is running and contains unsaved text?

Answer (score 2):

> Gedit is running

`pidof gedit` should give you the answer

> contains unsaved text

As far as I know Gedit doesn't support any DBus interface which makes this task relatively difficult but possible:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

for i in `pidof gedit`; do
    for j in `xdotool search --name --onlyvisible --pid $i`; do
        title=`xdotool getwindowname $j`
        case $title in
            \**)
                echo "Found running Gedit with unsaved data"
            ;;
            *)
                echo "Gedit is open but there are no unsaved documents"
            ;;
        esac
    done
done
```

What this script does. It iterates over all found gedit processes, finds their visible windows, iterates over their titles and checks if the title contains `*` as the first character which indicates an unsaved document.

Bash/shell purists will probably want to replace ``` `` ``` with `$( )`.